# An issue with Arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to keep a static array list so i can call it globally in my flash application when needed, however it doesn't seem to be adding any values into the array list.

```
package com.globals
{
    import com.player.PlayerBullets;
    import com.ships.enemy.SpaceDrone;
    import com.globals.Globals;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MCActiveLibrary 
    {
        private static var enemyShips:Array = new Array();
        private static var enemyBullets:Array = new Array();
        private static var playBullets:Array = new Array();

        public static function addPlayerBullets(bullets:PlayerBullets):void
        {
            playBullets.push(bullets);
            trace(playBullets[1]);
            bullets.id = playBullets.length -=1;
            trace("array Length:"+ bullets.id + "\nbullet ID:"+playBullets.length+"\n");
            Globals._stage.addChild(bullets);
        }
        public static function getPlayerBullets(i:int):PlayerBullets
        {
            return playBullets[i];
        }
        public static function removePlayerBullets(i:int):void
        {   
        trace(i);
            Globals._stage.removeChild(playBullets[i]);
            //updatePositions(playerBullets, i+1);
            //playerBullets.splice(i, 1);
        }
}
```

The run time error i get is..

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>       at com.globals::MCActiveLibrary$/removePlayerBullets()[H:\HobbyProject\SpaceDevils\com\globals\MCActiveLibrary.as:28]
>       at com.player::PlayerBullets/eFrame()[H:\HobbyProject\SpaceDevils\com\player\PlayerBullets.as:30]

and as for the trace commands being ran

> [object PlayerBullets]
>   array Length:0
>   bullet ID:0
>   0

This one has got me a little stumped, especially considering the object PlayerBullets is being found in position 0 of the array, even though the array length is 0.

Much thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: Why did your write `playBullets.length -=1` instead of `playBullets.length - 1`?

Comment: Explain this - Globals._stage

Comment: Yeah.. pretty much.. thanks kodiak

@neil, thats a class designed so i can access the stage from wherever i need it. Helps in this case so i can dynamically store an array of objects in a class that doesnt have direct access to the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line

```
bullets.id = playBullets.length -=1;
```

to

```
bullets.id = playBullets.length - 1;
```

your line changes the length of the array, instead of setting the bullets.id.

also, array's are zero-indexed, so trace(playBullets[1]); will fail since there is just 1 object in the array, at index 0, instead of index 1. replace it with trace(playBullets[0]);

Comment: Wow, thanks. How did i miss some thing so simple.. Must be going blind. Thanks marijin